# How far can I be from Britain and be in "British X"?

Tags: uk, factoids, around-the-world, locate-this

This is a just for fun question.

I'm studying in British Columbia, Canada, which is quite far away from Great Britain proper: 4,190 miles (6743 km) to be exact.

I'm wondering, though, how far could I be from Britain and be somewhere called "British X"? For example, British Virgin Islands.

I'll accept other regional terms from the UK, like New South Wales, or unofficial regions like New England.

Comment: The farthest would be the antipodes of Great Britain so anything in New Zealand would probably win. Short of that or maybe some remote island somewhere between New Zealand, Australia and Antarctica, New South Wales looks quite good. But Zealand/Zeeland itself is Dutch, not British, and the small islands I can think of are named after people (including some British people), not places/regions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canterbury,_New_Zealand perhaps?

Comment: Dunedin, New Zealand? (Another name for Edinburgh)

Comment: The asteroid, London, is 600,000 miles away. Beat that! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets_named_after_places#United_Kingdom

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about travel but rather one of geography and place naming

Comment: @Calchas We have *so* many such factoids questions on TSE. I am voting to keep this one too open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are looking for territories named `British XYZ`, below is a non-comprehensive list of these, ordered by distance (feel free to add more territories). All distances were measured using [the Daft Logic Distance Calculator](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm), using the search string `United Kingdom` as a starting point for calculations.

- [New Britain (Connecticut, USA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Britain,_Connecticut): 5102.123km
- [New Britain (Pennsylvania, USA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Britain,_Pennsylvania): 5353.193km
- [British Virgin Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Virgin_Islands): 6533.172km
- [British Columbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia): 6865.846km
- [British Indian Ocean Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Indian_Ocean_Territory): 9810.779km
- [New Britain (Papua New Guinea)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Britain): 14054.549km
- [British Antarctic Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Antarctic_Territory): 15075.884km (computed by pinpointing a region roughly at the centre of mass of the territory)

Comment: Suggestion: New Britain in PNG.

Comment: Great, quite comprehensive. I have a feeling the British Antarctic Territory will probably take the cake, unless someone comes up with another one.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for somewhere near the [*antipode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes) of Great Britain, which is closest to New Zealand. It's hard to tell without looking at a detailed map, but the [Chatham Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatham_Islands) are quite far from several places named "Chatham" in the UK.

New Zealand is full of nearby places with UK-derived names: Christchurch, Canterbury, Dunedin, even a rural intersection called [Charing Cross](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/@-43.5442796,172.1581249,3374m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en).